# Block User Agent when it is a number - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, block, user-agent, bots

I've been receiving a lot of visits to my site from bad bots.

The pattern is this:

```
190.204.58.162 - - [20/Oct/2014:16:46:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 318 mysite.com "-" "881087" "-"

201.243.204.1 - - [20/Oct/2014:16:46:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 318 mysite.com "-" "442762" "-"

200.109.59.218 - - [20/Oct/2014:16:46:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 318 mysite.com "-" "717724" "-"

113.140.25.4 - - [20/Oct/2014:16:46:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 318 mysite.com "-" "360319" "-"

183.136.221.6 - - [20/Oct/2014:16:46:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 318 mysite.com "-" "989851" "-"

195.154.78.122 - - [20/Oct/2014:16:46:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 318 mysite.com "-" "122984" "-"

59.151.103.52 - - [20/Oct/2014:16:46:54 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 318 mysite.com "-" "375843" "-"
```

Different IP and different user-agent.

However, the user-agent is always a numeric and normally it is 6 characters long.

For example on the first line, the user-agent is "881087" instead of being something like "Chrome", "Opera", "Safari", etc.

Does anyone know how to block it via `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure can block that depends on what platform php or .net.

Personally I would use isnumeric on the User Agent. If its numeric you might use return from jsp die(); in php or response.end for .net.

As far as htaccess you might try a regex on the user agent.

Please let me know if you want the exact script for any of the above.